# If else in Sql Developer

Tags: oracle, if-statement, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to give condition in SQL Developer as follows:

1. I want to select some data where status will be 'A', 'B', 'C' for particular CustomerID. CustomerID is not primary key.
2. If CutomerId has status as 'A' then, in next row, if same CustomerId has status 'B' then I want to select that CustomerID.

Database :

Srno (Number, Primary Key), CustomerID(number), Status (varchar)

Sample Data :

```
Srno         CustomerId        Status

1            001               A

2            001               B

3            002               A

4            002               C
```

In above case, I want to select CustomerID 001 because given condition is true.

Comment: Can you give your current SQL statement? Or is it PL/SQL?

Comment: Sorry Patrick I have no idea for this sql query. So i dont have any input for you.

Comment: looks like you need lag analytical function, but if you don't give us any input, we can't help you.

Comment: Can you tell me what should be Input?

Comment: your table structure, and sample data could be

Comment: You should try to research by yourself first. StackOverflow is here to help you if you are stuck somewhere in your code, but we are not here to do all your work for free.

Answer (score 4):

Term 'next row' has no meaning in SQL unless you provide some ordering. If you mean something like 'I wish to select customers which have both status A and status B', it can be done like

```
select 
  a.customerid 
from 
  (select * from customer where status = 'A') a,
  (select * from customer where status = 'B') b
where
  a.customerid = b.customerid
```

If you mean it should be really next (ordered by srno, for example), it could be done with, say, [LAG](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions070.htm) analytical function. Something like

```
select customerid
from (
  select 
    customerid, 
    status, 
    lag (status) over (partition by customerid order by srno) prev_status
    from customer) c
where c.status = 'B' and c.prev_status = 'A'
```

Comment: This is the exact answer I wanted. Sorry for being unclear in posting question.